# Loading jsGrid by calling Controller/WebService in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jsgrid

Am really struggling to load the jsGrid using Controller service. Am not able to do it correctly.

I even tried the sample code from the jsGrid site demo but that too didn't work either it throws error at !this.data.length or grid doesn't load at all.

I get no data every time I try using below code.

Appreciate if anyone can help.

This is how am loading the jsGrid:

```
$(element).jsGrid({
   height: 300,
   width: "100%",
    filtering: true,
    sorting: true,
    paging: true,
    autoload: true,
    pageLoading: true,

    controller: {
        loadData: function (filter) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "../Common/GetData",
                data: filter,
                dataType: "JSON"
            });
        }
    },
    pageSize: 10,
    pageButtonCount: 5,
    pageIndex: 1,

    noDataContent: "No Record Found",
    loadIndication: true,
    loadIndicationDelay: 500,
    loadMessage: "Please, wait...",
    loadShading: true,

    fields: [
        { name: "Name", type: "textarea", width: 150 },
        { name: "Age", type: "number", width: 50 },
        { name: "Address", type: "text", width: 200 },
        { name: "Country", type: "select" },
         {
             name: "", type: "text", width: 50, sorting: false, filtering: false,
             itemTemplate: function (value) {
                 return '<div class="edit-container"><a class="edit-custom-field-link">Edit</a><div class="sort-icon-container"><div class="up-arrow-icon"></div><div class="down-arrow-icon"></div></div></div>';
             }
         }
        //{ name: "Married", type: "checkbox", title: "Is Married", sorting: false }
        //,{ type: "control" }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Don't forget to use: autoload: true , if not loadData won't be called

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use promises while loading data,

```
loadData: function(filter) {

  return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../Common/GetData",
        data: filter,
        dataType: "JSON"
    })

}
```

---

`return $.ajax({})` does return a Promise. thank you

Comment: Is it possible to load jsGrid using pageLoading=true option, coz the way it accepts the parameter is loadData: function(filter) {
return { data: (want to use service call), itemsCount: (use service call object)}. not sure how to bind service call with data object

Comment: DID THIS ACTUALLY WORK? I cannot get the grid to load I just get the grid coming up and saying 'not found' even though I can see my JSON being requested and sent back and I have console logging in all my events and they do appear.. This is so very frustrating because I cannot work out how to debug it. When I step through the underlying JQuery code it doesn't make nay sense to me. AAAARRRRRGGH!

Comment: Similar code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35907482/data-not-populating-the-table-created-using-jsgrid

Comment: I've posted in the other question the code that finally worked for me..... just returning $.ajax directly.

Comment: @irfan `return $.ajax({})` DOES return a Promise

Answer (score 6):

I too was having problems with JSGrid. I was using the following snippet (as some have suggested):

`

```
loadData:   function(filter) {
    console.log("LoadData called....")
    var d = $.Deferred();
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/secure/msgitems",
      data: filter
    }).done(function(response) {
      console.log(  response);
      d.resolve(response);
      return;
  });
 return d.promise();
 },
},
```

`

I could see the results coming back, but my jsGrid kept puking. It turns out the server must return the data in the following format:

`{

    data: [items],
    itemsCount: amountOfItems 
}`

Here is where the developer discusses this topic: https://github.com/tabalinas/jsgrid/issues/35

It seems to work...FWIW

Comment: This actually works really well, and it allows you to handle the `fail()` as well as `done()` giving you the choice to handle that and alert the user / handle the error.

Answer (score 0):

To return a promise try this code for loadData:

```
            loadData: function() {
            var d = $.Deferred();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '../Common/GetData',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    d.resolve(data);
                },
                error: function(e) {
                    alert("error: " + e.responseText);
                }
            });

            return d.promise();
        }
```